# How to perform a JavaScript function when this specific onclick event is performed?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, xhtml, dom-events

I am not so into JavaScript and I have the following problem.

Into a JSP page I have some "links" like this:

```
<tr onmouseout="Javascript: this.style.background='#EAEFFF'; this.style.color='#003399';" onmouseover="Javascript: this.style.background='#003399'; this.style.color='#FFFFFF'; this.style.cursor='hand';" style="background-color: #EAEFFF;" onclick="Javascript: document.location.href='edi.do?serv=4.1';">
    <td>
        <!--A HREF="edi.do?serv=4.1" class="linkBlue" onMouseOver="self.status='Comunicazioni'; return true"-->
        Comunicazioni
    </td>
</tr>
```

As you can see in the previous code snippet the link is not yet implemented by a classic `a href` but, in its place, it is done by JavaScript using this expression:

```
onclick="Javascript: document.location.href='edi.do?serv=4.1';"
```

So, correct me if I am saying wrong assertion, I think that (when the user click on the **tr**) by the `Javascript:` it perform the following JavaScript operation that open the link. Is it the correct interpretation?

It works but my problem is that, before doing it, I have to perform a specific `loadingPopUp()` JavaScript function defined into the

```
<script type="text/javascript">...</script>
```

section of my page. So my problem is: how can I perform the `loadingPopUp()` function before the `Javascript: document.location.href='edi.do?serv=4.1';` on the`onclick` event?

Answer (score 1):

change `onclick` event to:

```
onclick="changeLocationTo('edi.do?serv=4.1')"
```

create a new js function:

```
function changeLocationTo(newLocation)
{
   loadingPopUp();

   // you may add an timeout here or to handle a popup action like closing it

   document.location.href = newLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Your assertion is absolutely right. But I think if you call your function before changing url then it would not be correct approach because second function will be executed immediately after your **loadingpopup** function and will redirect user to different page, so I think your purpose of opening popup will not be fulfilled.

So try this

**Way 1:** if you want to load your popup and immediately redirect user

```
function fnOpenNewLink(){
    loadingPopUp();
    document.location.href='edi.do?serv=4.1';
}
```

**Way 2:** if you want to load your popup and then redirect user according to your requirement.

```
function fnOpenNewLink(){
    loadingPopUp(function(){
        document.location.href='edi.do?serv=4.1';
    });
}

function loadingPopUp(callback){

    //your stuff

    //when everything is done, just call the callback
    callback();
}
```